# Downloading Multiple Files using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to download multiple files using C#, I have files in a directory on server, and on button click I am downloading them. The problem arising is that its downloading only one file, even if I have two or more files in directory
below is my code

```
string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(Directoryname);
foreach (String f in filenames)
{
       System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
       response.ClearContent();
       response.Clear();
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)));
       response.TransmitFile(f);
       response.Flush();
       response.End();    
}
```

I also tried with this but its giving exception, "Duplicate headers received from the server"

```
string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(Directoryname);
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
foreach (String f in filenames)
{                    
      response.ClearContent();
      response.Clear();
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)));
       response.TransmitFile(f);                      
}

response.Flush();
response.End();
```

I can have one or more then one file, but atleast one file.

Comment: what exception you are getting for the second option?

Comment: you can zip the files and then you can use download zip file.

Comment: @Shekhar check my updated question, I am already having zip file, I have to extract it automatically then download the content

Comment: You're looking at something like the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224784/how-to-download-multiple-files-using-asp-and-c-sharp. You cannot download multiple files from a web server in one request unless they are packaged in some way. Personally I would leave the files zipped (or create a new archive with only the files I wanted them to download) and get the user to unzip it themselves.

Comment: As the rest have mentioned there is no way to download several files in one request but you can create a javascript that creates multiple iFrames and assign one file to each iframe, this way multiple downloads might start downloading but I think that some browsers might block this(and I hope they do :P)