# Saving in a Loop with EPPlus

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, epplus

I'm trying to generate Excel files in loop with EPplus,

there is my function :

```
Function CreerExcel(ByVal val1 As String, ByVal val2 As String, ByVal val3 As String, ByVal val4 As String, ByVal val5 As String)
    'Ouverture de mon fichier Excel existant
    Dim ExistFile = Server.MapPath("~/Styles/Excel/fiche_evaluation.xlsx")

    Dim File = New FileInfo(ExistFile)

    'Définition du package EPplus
    Using package As New ExcelPackage(File)
        package.Load(New FileStream(ExistFile, FileMode.Open))

        'Selection de l'onglet de travail (Excel)
        Dim workSheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
        'Ecriture
        workSheet.Cells("B6").Value = val1
        workSheet.Cells("F6").Value = val2
        workSheet.Cells("C7").Value = val3
        workSheet.Cells("G7").Value = val4
        workSheet.Cells("C8").Value = val5
        'Enregistrement du nouveau fichier
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Eval_" & val1 & "-" & val5 & ".xlsx")
        Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Using

End Function
```

I'm working with VB, When i'm call this function, it work, but if my loop, loop X times, i could just save the first file. I wanted to save all the files !

When i'm replace

```
Response.end()
```

By

```
Response.clear()
```

My loop work the first time but after that :

" Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent. "

Could someone help me ???

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224784/how-to-download-multiple-files-using-asp-and-c-sharp), which has some suggestions (zip the files, or open multiple windows/tabs through script on the client)?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but it seems that what i have to do (On other Forums and Help Chat they told me the same things)